# how to create subdomain in windows server 2016

Tags: windows, server, subdomain

how to create a sub domain in windows server 2016? I have working on creating a sub domain in my windows server 2016. I have created multiple domains earlier and all are working fine. But when i created a sub domain for one of that domain .it cannot be accessed from other systems. Could anyone give me a solution?